# pointer argument in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, function, pointers, arguments

I have this simple function in php and the parameter is a pointer. What is the equivalent of this in JavaScript.

```
<?php

    function test( &$val )
        {
        echo    $val;
        $val ++;
        }

    $value  = 5;
    test( $value );
    echo    $value
?>
```

Can be done using an object as parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no equivalent in javascript, but you could use variables in a higher scope as a workaround as noted in the answer by Patrick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While primitives like numbers,strings etc cannot be passed by reference, all objects/arrays are. So to do what you want first put your value in an object and then pass it

```
var container = {
   myvalue:5
};

function changeVal(obj){
   obj.myvalue = 8;
}

console.log(container.myvalue); //prints: 5
changeVal(container);
console.log(container.myvalue); //prints: 8
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, very useful and an easy way to implement on my project.